# How to detect the existence of a function (NOT class member) with a specific name and signature using type_traits in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

Trying to accomplish the following:

```
// Template not necessary, but shows the pattern
template <typename T>
bool MyFunction(const T&, const uint8_t);

template <T>
struct is_myfunc_defined : std::false_type{}

// How do I properly create this
template <typname R, typename... Args>
struct is_myfunc_defined<R MyFunction(args....)> : std::true_type
{
};

struct MyStruct1 {};
struct MyStruct2 {};

// Will Match
bool MyFunction(const MyStruct&, const uint8_t){ return true; }
// Will not match
bool ShouldFail1(const MyStruct2&, const uint8_t){ return true; }
void MyFunction(const MyStruct2&, const uint8_t){ return true; }
bool MyFunction(const MyStruct2&){ return true; }

int main()
{
    cout << is_myfunc_defined<MyStruct>::value << endl; // true
    cout << is_myfunc_defined<MyStruct2>::value << endl; // false
}
```

I know how to use is_detected_exact to check for a class method with a specific return type, name, and signature, but how does one do it with a straight up function. Can't figured it out, need help.

Thanks!

Comment: The name of a function is not part of it's type.  You really need reflection for something like that.  Hopefully C++23 will have it.

Comment: You cannot do this generically (as there is no way to pass a "name" to check for through templates). But it is possible to check for the presence of a certain named member.

Comment: Yea, that is what I was thinking too, just figured if there was a dummy type that called that signature, maybe that could be tested in a type_trait...

Comment: The example looks weird to me. Shouldn't it be `is_myfunc_defined<bool(MyStruct, uint8_t)>::value` instead of `is_myfunc_defined<MyStruct>::value`?

Comment: Yea, its not correct, hence the comment. Just trying to convey the point

Comment: Why do you think you need this? What if the function is part of an overload set, is a function template, or has default arguments?

Comment: Was thinking about something like boost::serialization, where there is the option to do a non-intrusive serializer (i.e. function). How would the you know in a specialization whether the instrusive vs non-intrusive was available and not cause a compile error. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39efd4c1600c2460 Is this what you wanted?

Comment: That looks like it should work. It was the name matching that I wasn't sure how to do. Can you put this as a solution and provide a brief description of why this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know how to use `is_detected_exact` to check for a class method

It's no different for a global function:

```
template <typename ...P>
using detect_myfunc = decltype(MyFunction(std::declval<P>()...));

template <typename T>
struct is_myfunc_defined {};

template <typename R, typename ...P>
struct is_myfunc_defined<R(P...)>
    : std::experimental::is_detected_exact<R,detect_myfunc,P...> {};
{};
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.